# Is it possible to define a C++11 variadic class template whose variadic parameter cardinality depends on an integer template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Sorry for the convoluted question, but basically the idea is very simple. I have a variadic class template:

```
template<class P1, class P2, class ... P3s>
class A 
{
    ...
};
```

I would like to have an A-classes generator which takes an integer template parameter N and instantiates an A class with N P3s parameters. Like:

```
template<class P1, class P2, class P3, int N>
class GenA : /* somehow */ : public A<P1, P2, /* N times */ P3, P3, ...>
{
    ...
};
```

So usage would be:

```
// Generates A<Class1, Class2, Class3, Class3, Class3>
GenA<Class1, Class2, Class3, 3> a;
```

I have already tried doing that with compile time recursion and partial specialization

```
template <class P1, class P2, int N, class P3>
class GenA : public GenA<P1, P2, N-1, P3, P3>
{
    ...
}

template <class P1, class P2, int N, class ... P3s>
class GenA<P1, P2, 0, P3s ...> : public A<P1, P2, P3s, ...>
{
    ...
}
```

however C++11 doesn't recognize the second template to be a specialization of the first one (because it is, in fact, different) and never gets to the base case of the recursion (it stops complaining about too many recursion levels). Any ideas?

Thanks
Tunnuz

Comment: Seems hard to do without excessive template specializations.

Comment: After you have chosen one of the answers, could you provide a benchmark of the solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class P1, class P2, class... P3s>
class A {};

template<class... Ps>
struct TypeList {};

template<class P1, class P2, class P3, unsigned N, class P> struct GenHelp;

template<class P1, class P2, class P3, class... Ps>
struct GenHelp<P1, P2, P3, 0, TypeList<Ps...> >
{
   typedef A<P1, P2, Ps... > AType;
};

template<class P1, class P2, class P3, unsigned N, class... Ps>
struct GenHelp<P1, P2, P3, N, TypeList<Ps...> > : public GenHelp<P1, P2, P3, N-1, TypeList<P3, Ps...> >
{};

template<class P1, class P2, class P3, unsigned N>
class GenA : public GenHelp<P1, P2, P3, N, TypeList<> >::AType
{};
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'll take this because it's similar to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use variadic template template parameters to do this. In this
implementation we simply start with an argument pack consisting of
`P1` and `P3` and keep extending it. At the end we instantiate the
variadic template template parameter with that argument pack.

```
template<class P1, class P2, class ... P3s>
struct A {};

template<template<class... Args> class AT, typename P3, int N, 
         typename... Already>
struct GenAImpl {
  typedef typename GenAImpl<AT, P3, N - 1, Already..., P3>::type type;
};

template<template<class... Args> class AT, typename P3, 
         typename... Already>
struct GenAImpl<AT, P3, 0, Already...> {
  typedef AT<Already...> type;
};


template<class P1, class P2, class P3, int N>
struct GenA : GenAImpl<A, P3, N, P1, P2>
{};

int main()
{
  GenA<int, double, float, 3>::type X;
  return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that appending to lists is often a bad idea (at least in
real functional languages, I have no idea if that actually impacts C++
compiler performance) and you are better of with consing it together
and reversing it at the end.